# Using Angular to set the html form type

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use Angular to display a form that contains all the properties for an object. Some of those objects are passwords and I want angular to use the password form type for those.

So far I've gotten it working by setting the type attribute to an angular method, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner angular syntax for it (like how you can use ng-href instead of href)

Sample html code:

```
    <form name="siteSettingsForm" novalidate class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="save()">
        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="property in siteProperties">
            <label for="{{ property }}" class="control-label col-sm-3">{{ property }}</label>
            <input id="{{ property }}" type="{{ getPropertyFormType(property) }}" ng-model="site[property]" class="form-control col-sm-9" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Controller code:

```
app.controller("settingsController", [
    '$scope', 
    function ($scope) {

        $scope.site = {
            basic_auth_username: "myUsername",
            basic_auth_password: "hide me"
        };

        $scope.siteProperties = [];
        for (var property in $scope.site) {
            if ($scope.site.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                $scope.siteProperties.push(property);
            }
        }

        $scope.getPropertyFormType = function(property) {
            if (property.indexOf("password") > -1) {
                return "password";
            } else {
                return "text";
            }
        }
}]);
```

So question: is there a better way to use Angular to specify the type in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity: I ended up using the method I described in my question

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ng-attr section [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  You can use that to decorate the type attribute.  Although as you are not allowed to dynamically switch input types anyway, I don't see a clear advantage to using it one way or the other.  The way you are doing it (hardcoding when DOM is loaded) will work just fine for your purposes.

Depending on the shape of your object, you might be able to clean up your function and just put it straight into your Angular expression in your HTML.